# Changing Labels and Static Text per Client using ASP.net MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, asp.net-mvc-3

I am currently designing a multi-tenant website where many clients will share the same code base but have their own "look-and-feel" to the site when the are logged in.  This is nothing new, but I am looking for ideas on the best way to implement the solution using ASP.NET and MVC3 (which looks awesome).

The main thing I am looking at now is how to change the CSS style-sheet and text for the labels and static portions of the pages per client.  So this would be something like localization where I would want to just have a string in the Razor template, like @FirstNameLabel and then at runtime it would grab the specific value setup for the logged in client for that variable.

I know I could implement this with a database, but I am just making sure there isn't some clever way to do this in .NET (I have been in the Java world for several years now).  It seems like I could possibly use a variation of localization or globalization with ResourceManager, but I haven't found any examples that were not based on cultures, which I do not want/need at this time.

Any ideas are greatly appreaciated!

Comment: Have you found any solution to this question?

Answer (score -1):

You could use a custom VirtualPathProvider class to deliver different views (even though the URL is the same) based on some user setting. That way, you could have different views that contained different text, stylesheets, etc...

Check here for more info [ASP.NET MVC and virtual views](http://www.umbraworks.net/bl0g/rebuildall/2009/11/17/ASP_NET_MVC_and_virtual_views)

Comment: This method would probably create more work than is feasible in a real multi-tenant environment. Adding a new client shouldn't require that new views need to be created and deployed. This also makes maintenance a nightmare as all the views would have to be updated any time that "page" changed.

Comment: Did you have a better suggestion @mikeschuld? The storage location can be anywhere (file, database, cloud storage, or all of the above), so each tenant could read from the same location, but certain small partial views could be overridden (containing things such as logo, title, etc) from different places. The VirtualPathProvider could read from the normal location for views, and certain file locations could be intercepted and load custom user content. So your assumption that each customer would have to have their own entire set of views is not what I was implying. I was only offering one way.